# Is it possible to use stock UI for incomming call but custom UI for outgoing call?

Tags: android, voip, phone-call

I am developing calling app using `ConnectionServiсe`. As described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/) there are two modes:

- **self-managed**, where application has to provide UI.
- **system-managed**, where application uses stock phone app UI.

For my purposes stock incoming call screen fits well, but stock outgoing screen is not suitable.

Is there a way to use stock incoming call UI, but custom outgoing call UI?